Is there a stable bottom sheet in compose?
I want to make a bottom sheet in my app but all bottom sheets are expermental. So what does someone do when dealing with a production app? It is not good practice to use expermental components
I tried to use recently bottom sheets like modalbottomsheetlayout. I thought it will be ok to be used in a production app, but I found it is experimental

Note that the ModalBottomSheetLayout and related APIs were made non-experimental in Compose Material 1.7.0-alpha03.

What's experimental about the bottom sheets is the exposed API, not the functionality. That's why the annotation is called @ExperimentalMaterial3Api.
The risk by using the API is not that there could be lots of bugs (and therefore a risk to stability in prduction), the risk is that in the next compose release the API surface changes and you have to update your code (and therefore need to invest more time into maintainance).
As @ianhanniballake pointed out in the comments, the next compose version seem to graduate the bottom sheets from being experimental, so there won't be much harm starting to use them right now anyways.

I believe there is always a risk using a code marked as Experimental in production.

Yes, I didn't dispute that. But you are not risking production stability (which is usually the main reason why one refrains from using experimental code). Here, the risk is increased maintainance cost, which may be outweighed by the alternative to finding some other bottom sheet implementation. So it may very well be worth the risk to use in production.
